# How to convert a string into the sum of ASCII values?

Tags: c++, string, ascii

I am a beginner and taking a CSC course, I have to write a program that converts a user input string into the sum of the ASCII value of each character, here is what I have so far, and Im still pretty far from being done. But any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;
using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
    {
        int x;

        std::cout << "enter string" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> x;
    }
    string text = "STRING";

    for (int i = 0; i < text.size(); i++)
        cout << (int)text[i] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are you having trouble with?

Comment: Presumably, ASCII is used here as a [genericized trademark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_trademark) (like Kleenex or Xerox). The general term is "character code". The character encoding could vary from system to system, terminal to terminal, user to user and time to time and is almost certainly not ASCII. Different character encodings could have different character codes for the same entered string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a range-based `for` loop to traverse the string and then add up each `char` within:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    int sum = 0; // this is where all the values are being added to
    std::string s;
    std::cout << "enter string and press enter." << std::endl;
    std::cin >> s; // string that the user enters will be stored in s

    for (char c : s)
        sum += c;
    std::cout << "total ASCII values: " << sum << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```